# Inserting image into NSViews pageFooter

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsattributedstring, nstextattachment

I've been trying to insert an image into the page footer of a custom NSView, so that when I print it, it will display text and an image in the footer. Here is the code that I am using:

```
- (NSAttributedString *)pageFooter {                                                            
    NSString *imgName = @"Logo.tif";                                                            
    NSFileWrapper *fwrap = [[[NSFileWrapper alloc] initRegularFileWithContents:         
                 [[NSImage imageNamed:@"Logo"] TIFFRepresentation]] autorelease];
    [fwrap setFilename:imgName];
    [fwrap setPreferredFilename:imgName];

    NSTextAttachment * ta = [[[NSTextAttachment alloc] initWithFileWrapper:fwrap] autorelease];
    NSString *aString = @"Foo";
    NSMutableAttributedString *bString = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc]initWithString:aString]];
    [bString appendAttributedString:[NSAttributedString attributedStringWithAttachment:ta]];
    return bString;                                                                                     
    [bString release];                                                                                  
}
```

This doesn't display the image, however it does display the text.
What have I done wrong?

I've got the Logo.tif in the Resources folder in Xcode, and it is in the main project folder on my desktop. I've also tried with Logo.tiff (with the extra 'f')

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: You need to move that `release` message above the `return` statement. `return` does not just mean “return a value to the caller”; it also means “return execution to the caller”. Thus, your function (or method, in this case) stops executing when you `return` from it; that means you never reach this `release` message statement, so you never send the message, so you leak `bString` every time.

Comment: (If you already know some of that, please take no offense; I don't know how much you know, and I'd rather tell you things you already know than not tell you things you need to know.)

Comment: Thanks for that advice, I actually didn't realise that I did that, so that's very helpful :)